# Reading a ps1 file from C# / powershell and C# runspace

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to run the following simple ps1 file (which works fine if I call it from powershell) from Visual C#.

---

[windowsErrorReporting.ps1]

```
    Get-WindowsErrorReporting

    if($WER_ENABLED -eq "True")
    {
        Enable-WindowsErrorReporting
    }
    else
    {
        Disable-WindowsErrorReporting
    }

    Get-WindowsErrorReporting // *1
```

The following is the C# code I wrote, and here is the situation I got:

- Suppose I turned off Windows Error Reporting from the C# runspace.
- When I turn it off from C#, the second Get-WindowsErrorReporting (the line I marked as *1 above)
  shows that the setting was properly changed.
- However, when I type Get-WIndowsErrorReporting on another powershell window, the value is still not changed.
- I also tried the other way around : Change the state from the powershell window, and check the state from the C# code... This time, I get "disabled" from the powershell window, and "enabled" from the C# runspace.

  - From what I saw, I guess there is no "Link" between the powershell "sessions"(sorry I don't know how they call it...) of the powershell window and C# runspace...

---

```
    private string RunScript(string scriptFileName)
    {
        // Read text data from the script file.
        string cmd;
        var assm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        using (var stream = assm.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources."+scriptFileName))
        {
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
            cmd = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // create powershell runspace
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        // open it
        runspace.Open();

        // Create a pipeline and feed it the script text
        Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmd);

        pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
        foreach (string key in args.Keys)
        {
            runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("WER_ENABLED", "False");
        }

        Collection<PSObject> results;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // execute the script
        results = pipeline.Invoke();

        // convert the script result into a single string
        foreach (PSObject obj in results)
        {
             stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }

        // Close the runspace
        runspace.Close();

        // Return output
        return stringBuilder.ToString();

    }
```

---

I really appreciate if someone help me understand what is going on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED!]
The reason I could not get the script working was that I run x86 version of the powershell from C#.
That is why I get different results from the powershell window (x64) and the powershell runspace (x86).
After I configured the visual C# compiler setting to build x64, everything worked fine.

What I learned from this problem is that some powershell commands, like Enable-WindowsErrorReporting, do not run on x86 version of powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Check the result returned from `Enable/Disable-WindowsErrorReporting`. If it returns `False` it didn't work.  I believe you have to be running as admin for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I checked the output of Enable/Disable-WindowsErrorReporting, and turned out they return true. I also realized that same thing happens when I use x86 powershell window. So, I will try calling x64 powershell from C# and update this thread.